# Windows Phone 10 universal app, event on incoming call, show custom toast/screen

Tags: c#, windows-phone, win-universal-app

We need to show a toast or similar when the phone rings from a pre-defined number.

This is for an in-house application so we can use private APIs.

Long story short - when calls are routet trough our main number/line to our cell phones, we need to grab extra information from the phone central and display on the screen to the employee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked [Caller ID sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CallerID)? You can register a Caller ID background task to be triggered when an incoming call arrives. The task sets the call location, category, category description and display name of the call.

If you want to do block and filter related work, you can also refer to [Communication blocking and filtering sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CommunicationBlockAndFilter) for more details.

If you are Microsoft employee and want to use private api, I suggest you ask internally. (Just search internally and I believe you will find the right person.)

Comment: Thanks. I've missed that one. I'll look into the Caller ID sample.

I'm not a Microsoft employee, so I cannot ask internally. Tought maybe there where some non documented APIs that we could use, but this one is even better. Thanks again.